# concatenate every 3 columns in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a big data frame with 713 columns and 10 rows, I want to concatenate every 3 columns starting from column 6, variable names are from v1 to v713.

the data looks like this:

```
> chr1[,1:10]
  V1  V2   V3  V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14........
1  1 rs1  116  T  G  1  0  0  0   1   0   0   1   0 
2  1 rs2  118  G  A  1  0  0  1   0   0   0   1   0  
3  1 rs3  230  A  G  1  0  0  1   0   0   0   1   0
```

results needed:

```
  V1  V2   V3  V4 V5  V6  V7   V8..........
1  1 rs1  116  T  G  100  010  010
2  1 rs2  118  G  A  100  100  010
3  1 rs3  230  A  G  100  100  010
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the columns to be concatenated starts from 6th position, we subset that as a different object ('df2'), `split` it to every three columns using a grouping variable created with `gl`, `paste` the elements of rows together (`do.call(paste0`) by looping over the `list` of `data.frame`, `cbind` with the first 5 columns and update the column names

```
df2 <- df1[6:ncol(df1)]
dfN <- cbind(df1[1:5], sapply(split.default(df2, as.integer(gl(ncol(df2),
             3, ncol(df2)))), function(x) do.call(paste0, x)))
colnames(dfN) <- paste0("V", seq_along(dfN))
dfN
#  V1  V2  V3 V4 V5  V6  V7  V8
#1  1 rs1 116  T  G 100 010 010
#2  1 rs2 118  G  A 100 100 010
#3  1 rs3 230  A  G 100 100 010
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse` where we concatenate the columns 'V6' to the last one to a single column 'VNew' with `unite` and then `separate` it to multiple columns with the `sep` argument which takes numeric positions as well

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    unite(VNew, V6:V14, sep="") %>%
    separate(VNew, into = c("V6", "V7", "V8"), sep=c(3, 6))
#  V1  V2  V3 V4 V5  V6  V7  V8
#1  1 rs1 116  T  G 100 010 010
#2  1 rs2 118  G  A 100 100 010
#3  1 rs3 230  A  G 100 100 010
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), V2 = c("rs1", "rs2", "rs3"
), V3 = c(116L, 118L, 230L), V4 = c("T", "G", "A"), V5 = c("G", 
"A", "G"), V6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), V7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), V8 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), V9 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), V10 = c(1L, 0L, 0L), V11 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), V12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), V13 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), V14 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
 "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```